# Creating a methods who's parameters are a class and a generic ArrayList

Tags: java, class, object, methods, arraylist

Im my program I have copy and pasted code (an obvious no-no) because I haven't figured out how to pass the parameters I want to this method:

```
public String collectionToFormattedString() {
    String combined = "";
    for (Book b : LibObj.books) {
        combined =  combined + b.toString() + "<br />";
    }
    combined = "<HTML>" + combined +"</HTML>";
    return combined;
}
```

I want to pass parameters to do the following:

```
public String collectionToFormattedString(Object? XYZ, ArrayList ABC) {
    String combined = "";
    for (XYZ b : ABC) {
        combined =  combined + b.toString() + "<br />";
    }
    combined = "<HTML>" + combined +"</HTML>";
    return combined;
}
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
public <T> String collectionToFormattedString(T XYZ, List<T> ABC) {
    String combined = "";
    for (T b : ABC) {
        combined =  combined + b.toString() + "<br />";
    }
    combined = "<HTML>" + combined +"</HTML>";
    return combined;
}
```

**EDIT**

I just realized you don't even use the first param, and as @rgettman points out, you are not using any operations specific to `T`, so you could simplify this to:

```
public String collectionToFormattedString(final List<?> list) {
    StringBuilder combined = new StringBuilder("<HTML>");
    for (Object elem : list) {
        combined.append(elem.toString()).append("<br />");
    }
    combined.append("</HTML>");
    return combined.toString();
}
```

Comment: Based on how the OP was using XYZ, I think that it was an attempt to specify that class type in the list. If this is true, you don't need the argument at all.

Comment: @unholysampler: Yeah, just realized that too. :)

Comment: There's nothing specific about `T`: It's not being returned, and no `T`-specific methods are called.  It could be `public String collectionToFormattedString(List<?> list) {` and `for (Object elem : list) {`

Answer (score 1):

```
public <T> String collectionToFormattedString(List<Book> XYZ) 
{
    StringBuilder combined = new StringBuilder();
    combined.Append("<HTML>");
    foreach (Book b in XYZ)
    {
        combined.Append(b.ToString() + "<br />");
    }
    combined.Append("</HTML>");

    return combined;
}
```

By the looks of it, you just need to make a collection of book, then pass that collection. If you don't like lists, you can do it with an array use a for loop with an increment-er. I like the string builder, lets you do fancy things with it, but just taking a string and '+' adding it together works just fine as well. Best of luck to you.

EDIT: Sorry for the post, was answered when I was pulled away from my desk in the middle of typing.